# Migrating from AngularJS .9 to 1.3 CRUD

Tags: angularjs, factory, ngresource, ngroute

I am upgrading my crud angular.9 to 1.3, upon doing so I realized the huge changes between the two. Since I am no guru with angular I decided to seek the community for help with this nasty error I keep getting.
Here is what I have:
My index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app="crm"  >
<head>
<title>CRM</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="RouteCtrl" >
<div id="content"  class="">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
<script src="lib/angularjs/angular.js" ng-autobind></script>
<script src="lib/angularjs/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angularjs/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my services.js:

```
    angular.module('crm',['ngResource','ngRoute'])
    .config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider' , function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/leads', { templateUrl:'tpl/leads.php', controller:LeadListCtrl }).
            when('/leads/add', {controller:LeadListCtrl, templateUrl:'tpl/leads.php'}).
            when('/leads/:leadId', { templateUrl:'tpl/leads.php', controller:LeadDetailCtrl , resolve: LeadDetailCtrl.resolve}).

            when('/customers', { templateUrl:'tpl/customers.php', controller:CustomerDetailCtrl }).
            when('/customers/:customerId', { templateUrl:'tpl/customers.php', controller:CustomerDetailCtrl }).

            otherwise({templateUrl:'tpl/welcome.php'});
    }]).
    factory('Lead', ['$resource', function($resource) {
        return $resource('api/leads/:leadId', {},
            { 'update': { method:'PUT' }
            });
    }]).
    factory('Customer', [function ($resource) {
        return $resource('api/customers/:customerId', {}, {
            update: {method:'PUT'}
        });
    }]);
```

Handler:

```
function CustomerListCtrl(Customer){
this.customers = Customer.query();
}

function CustomerDetailCtrl(Customer) {
var currentnotes;
this.customer = Customer.get({customerId: this.params.customerId});
}
```

Here is my error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost/crm_2/js/services.js:51:16)
at Object.invoke (http://localhost/crm_2/lib/angularjs/angular.js:4185:17)
at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (http://localhost/crm_2/lib/angularjs/angular.js:4038:37)
at Object.invoke (http://localhost/crm_2/lib/angularjs/angular.js:4185:17)
at http://localhost/crm_2/lib/angularjs/angular.js:4003:37
at getService (http://localhost/crm_2/lib/angularjs/angular.js:4144:39)
at invoke (http://localhost/crm_2/lib/angularjs/angular.js:4176:13)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost/crm_2/lib/angularjs/angular.js:4193:27)
at http://localhost/crm_2/lib/angularjs/angular.js:8462:28
at link (http://localhost/crm_2/lib/angularjs/angular-route.js:975:26) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

Any help will be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please add the dependencies correctly.

```
var crm = angular.module('crm',['ngResource','ngRoute']);
```

Comment: @WaelWahbeh isn't the proper syntax `crm.controller ('RouteCtrl ', ['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {` ? I'm new to Angular too, but I think that's why the dependency is not injected.

Comment: @EricPandaForce after changing the syntax I still get:

angular.js:11607 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'RouteCtrl' is not a function, got undefined